# What is the JSTL syntax for boolean method begining with the word "has"?

Tags: jsp, boolean, jstl

I'm using Java 6 with JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  I have a Java object on my JSP with this method

```
boolean hasNewUsers() {  ... }
```

What is the correct way to reference this on my JSP?  I tried

```
${myObj.newUsers}
```

but got an exception, "javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'org.mainco.subco.myproject.domain.MyObject' does not have the property 'newUsers'".

Comment: For accessor methods other than is....() get....() use the full method name and include the parenthesis: ${myObj.hasNewUsers()}. More recent versions of JSP EL also allow you to call methods which take parameters ${myObj.hasNewUsers(arg1)}.

Comment: If ou want to put that as the answer, I'll accept.